# Unable to connect to remote sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have an SQL Server 2008 hosted on a different computer in a different domain. I am able to ping to this machine using the IP address, but not using the machine name. I have also checked the settings of the sql server instance and it is configured to provide access to remote connections.
(Allow remote connections, tcp/ip enabled)

When I try to find this server using Sql server management studio 2008 or VS 2008, I get the error saying that the server cannot be found.

what could be the reason for this?

Comment: **SHOW US** the connection string!

Answer (score 1):

1. Please check SQL Browser service is running.
2. Please make sure you are providing valid authentication details.

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure that TCP/IP connections are allowed by the SQL Server instance by checking the [SQL Server Configuration Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174212.aspx). If you are using an express version of SQL Server then all remote connections are typically disabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a trust relationship between the domains I think, it's been a while since I've done things between domains.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Firewall will block SQL Server connection requests from a client machine by default. These are the steps I normally do to allow SQL Server through Windows Firewall:

1. Windows Firewall-> Allow app or feature through Windows Firewall-> Change 
   Settings-> Allow another app-> Browse to SQL Server exe (eg: C:\Program 
   Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL 
   Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe)-> Open-> Add.
2. Windows Firewall-> Allow app or feature through Windows Firewall-> Change 
   Settings-> Allow another app-> add SQL Brower service by going to 
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Shared\sqlbrowser.exe.
3. SQL Server configuration Manager-> SQL Server Network Configuration-> 
   Protocols for Your_SQL_Instance-> Right click TCP/IP on the right pane 
   and enable.

The SQL Server instance does not need to be configured to run on 1433 and therefore no need to open the 1433 port through the firewall. SQL Browser will find it for you whichever port it is running on.